# doing multiple tasks on jQuery toggle

Tags: jquery, toggle

I've 3 divs side by side.
By default 2 is hidden.
The center div is displayed.

What I want:

1. Clicking on the top-right of the center div will display the right div and the center div will make some space sliding left of its original space.
2. I want the same for the left div. Clicking the top-left side of the center div will display the left div pushing the center div a little to the right of its original space.
3. Also when clicked on the top-left of the center div when the right div is open the right div will disappear.
   Same goes for the left-div.

I'm using jQuery UI's toggle method. Everything is working except the no:3
I can show you the jQuery code I have.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var state = true;
$('#contact-screw').click(function(){
    $('#about-box').hide();
    $('#content-box').css('float', 'left');
    if (state) {
        $('#content-box').css('float', 'left');
    } else {
        $('#content-box').css('float', 'none');
    }   
    state = !state;
    $('#contact-box').toggle('explode', 'slow');        
});
$('#about-screw').click(function(){
    $('#contact-box').hide();
    $('#content-box').css('float', 'left');
    if (state) {
        $('#content-box').css('float', 'left');
    } else {
        $('#content-box').css('float', 'none');
    }   
    state = !state;
    $('#about-box').toggle('explode', 'slow');
}); 
});
```

Comment: Anyone around here? Am I asking something weird?

Comment: Can anyone please let me know if what I'm looking for is achievable?